# Dispatching store actions via utility files (RTK-Query)

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am currently implementing our websocket engine to our Redux-Toolkit store. Our websocket connection/reconnect & event handling logic is held in it's own utility file, because each RTK-Query endpoint uses the same websocket, and passes individual handlers to the util file.

This works quite nicely for our purposes, but I would also like to set the websocket connection state in store once the `open` `close` & `error` events trigger, for displaying loading states throughout the App.

Is it possible to trigger store dispatch events without using the useDispatch hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can just import `store` in the file where you need it and call `store.dispatch` - you just should not be doing that in React components.